# Make two pyramids joined at their tops 3D-printable

Tags: mesh

I am preparing a mesh for export to STL and 3D printing. In the algorithmically generated mesh there are several places where a single tetrahedron, modeled as four triangles, meets the rest of the surface at a single vertex. Is there a simple way to "thicken" around this one-vertex joint so that I can get something that is printable? I'd prefer an algorithmic solution since the surface is complicated and there will be a number of places at which this happens. I'm okay with the rest of the surface being modified slightly as long as the overall shape doesn't change too much.

Note that my blender knowledge is minimal. I tried subsurf + solidify, but the solidify acts very strangely in the vicinity of these points. I also tried subdividing the mesh (so that each triangular face of a tetrahedron is subdivided into many smaller triangles), but solidify doesn't seem to notice. Perhaps I am doing something wrong here.

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: How would you prefer for the joint to look? Are you sure there are too many to do by hand? Because the solution would probably involve python scripting. One way to do this with no python is to place a sphere at each of those problematic vertex and boolean union them in with the mesh. Also if you alt-d the object, assign wireframe modifier and boolean union the clone it might look interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts; I will look into duplicating as you suggest. I have tried adding a sphere at each point and I guess it works okay. Ideally I'd have a smooth transition from each face to each other without the abrupt inner-edge of the sphere-face boundary, but that may be the easiest reasonable thing.